# Python, how to keep program going after exception is caught

Tags: python, exception, pyodbc

probably a simple question as I fairly new to python and programming in general but I am currently working on improving a program of mine and can't figure out how to keep the program going if an exception is caught. Maybe I am looking at it the wrong way but for example I have something along these lines:

```
    self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run)
    self.thread.setDaemon(True)
    self.thread.start()

    def run(self):
        logging.info("Starting Awesome Program") 
        try:
            while 1:
                awesome_program(self)
    except:
        logging.exception('Got exception on main handler')
        OnError(self)

    def OnError(self):
        self.Destroy()
```

Obviously I am currently just killing the program when an error is reached. awesome_program is basically using pyodbc to connect and run queries on a remote database. The problem arises when connection is lost. If I don't catch the exceptions the program just freezes so I set it up as it is above which kills the program but this is not always ideal if no one is around to manually restart it. Is there an easy way to either keep the program running or restert it. Feel free to berate me for incorrect syntax or poor programming skills. I am trying to teach myself and am still very much a novice and there is plenty I don't understand or am probably not doing correctly. I can post more of the code if needed. I wasn't sure how much to post without being overwhelming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Catch the exception within the loop, and continue, even if an exception is caught.

```
def run(self):
        logging.info("Starting Awesome Program") 
        while 1:
            try:
                awesome_program(self)
            except:
                logging.exception('Got exception on main handler')
                OnError(self)
```

BTW:

- Your indentation seems messed up.
- I'd prefer `while True`. Python has `bool` type, unlike C, so when a bool is expected - give `while` a bool.

Comment: Damn it, I tried to get back here quick enough to answer my own question as I just tried the exact thing you mentioned, I put the exception in the loop. Thanks!! Woot, glad I was able to come to the same conclusion.

Comment: Sometimes, when you're stuck, clearly stating the question helps dfinding the answer on your own... ;-)

Comment: @ Thorsten Yep seemed to work this time. The formatting(idents) got messed up when copy/pasting and I will change the loop to while true:. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for this:

```
def run(self):
     while True:
         try:
             do_things()
         except Exception as ex:
             logging.info("Caught exception {}".format(ex))
```

Comment: Thanks, as above I didn't quite make it back in time to answer my own question. Just happy I came back with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Python Exception Handling](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions), and in particular `Try...Except`.  It will allow you to catch particular errors and handle them however you choose fit, even ignore them completely, if possible.  For example:

```
try:
    while something == True:
        do_stuff()
except ExceptionType:
    print "Something bad happened!" #An error occurred, but the script continues
except:
    print "Something worse happened!"
    raise #a worse error occurred, now we kill it
do_more_stuff()
```